# supervisor install is failing with preseed for ubuntu-12.04

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to setup supervisor via preseed for ubuntu-12.04. 
The installation fails with an error in software installation step. I figured that I need to specify a couple of dependencies and I have all three relevant .deb packages under iso-path/pool/extras/*deb . The path and method is proven with other simpler .deb packages. 
Here is the snippet from my preseed file:

...

d-i pkgsel/include string python-medusa-doc

d-i pkgsel/include string python-meld3

d-i pkgsel/include string supervisor

...

Has anyone else tried installing supervisor this way ? what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

If you included all the .deb packages in your iso, you can try including this at the end of your file. This is assuming you will delay the software installation until the very end:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target dpkg -i -R /pathtodir/dot-deb-files; \
in-target apt-get install -y openssh-server; \
in-target apt-get install -y #2_SOFTWARE_NAME; \
in-target apt-get install -y #3_SOFTWARE_NAME;
```

Copied syntax from this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977570